# Rsize a base64 picture on console project

Tags: c#, base64

I have this code in a WCF service - it's used to resize an image based on a Base64 string.

```
internal static string ResizeImage(string base64String, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

    Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);

    var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
    var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
    var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
    var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
    var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

    var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
    Graphics thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);

    thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
           
    thumbGraph.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    image.Dispose();

    using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream())
    {
        newImage.Save(ms2, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] imageBytes2 = ms2.ToArray();
        string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes2);
        return base64;
    }
}
```

I want to use it in a console project.

I saw that it s not possible to use the class `Image` or `Bitmap` in a console project. Is there a way to resize an image in a console project?

Is there a way to resize a base64 string without using these classes?

Comment: Why do you believe you can't use `Image` or `Bitmap` in a console app? Where did you see that??

Comment: It's possible ? I saw on a post in stackOverflow